# Searching for resources with the Stripe GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Does anyone know the syntax for searching for resources with the Stripe GEM? Looking at [the code here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/lib/stripe/resources/charge.rb), it looks like this should work:

```
Stripe::Charge.search(...)
```

But I'm getting the exception:

```
undefined method `search' for Stripe::Charge:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be the [right syntax](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/search?lang=ruby) for that function.

Search functionality was added to the gem earlier this year in [version 5.47.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/releases/tag/v5.47.0). Make sure that you've upgraded to a new enough version to give you access to that functionality.

Comment: ‍♂️ I didn't realize I was on an older version.